# Hacer un deploy a un bundle en netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, maven

Buenas noches comunidad

Estoy creando un bundle en netbeans, es un proyecto osgi con maven. Si intento hacer el deploy desde netbeans me da el siguiente error:

> --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api ---
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 4.237s Finished at: Thu Jan 26 21:19:34 ART 2017 Final
>   Memory: 7M/105M
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file (default-cli)
>   on project com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api: The parameters
>   'url' for goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file
>   are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file
>   (default-cli) on project com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api:
>   The parameters 'url' for goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file are missing or
>   invalid   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginParameterException: The
>   parameters 'url' for goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file are missing or
>   invalid   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:576)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:529)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     ... 19 more

Ahora, si ejecuta mvn clean deploy desde la consola de comandos, se despliega exitósamente el bundle.

> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api ---
>   [INFO] LOCK file:///C:/projects/felixbook/releases/repository.xml
>   [INFO] Downloading repository.xml [INFO] Computed bundle uri:
>   file:/C:/projects/felixbook/releases/com/packtpub/felix/com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api/1.5.0/com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api-1.5.0.jar
>   [INFO] Writing OBR metadata [INFO] Deploying
>   file:/C:/projects/felixbook/releases/com/packtpub/felix/com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api/1.5.0/com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api-1.5.0.jar
>   [INFO] Writing OBR metadata [INFO] Uploading repository.xml [INFO]
>   UNLOCK file:///C:/projects/felixbook/releases/repository.xml [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 8.057 s

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Cuál es la opción desde netbeans que permita ejecutar el comando mvn clean deploy?.

Ya que desde la ventana Navigator ejecuto el proceso bundle deploy-file y termina en error, quizás deba usar otra opción desde netbeans. Me confunde el hecho que funcione mediante la línea de comando y no desde el IDE. Detallo mi archivo pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.packtpub.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf-inventory-api OSGi Bundle</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-Category>sample</Bundle-Category>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${artifactId}
                    </Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Export-Package>
                        com.packtpub.felix.bookshelf.inventory.api
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
                <remoteOBR>repo-rel</remoteOBR>
                <prefixUrl>file:///C:/projects/felixbook/releases</prefixUrl>
          <ignoreLock>true</ignoreLock>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

repo-rel
      file:///C:/projects/felixbook/releases

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-for-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- To include a shell:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.gogo.shell</artifactId>
                <version>0.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                        <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                        <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="bundles">
                                        <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                        <mapper>
                                            <chainedmapper>
                                                <flattenmapper/>
                                                <globmapper from="*" to="file:modules/*" casesensitive="no"/>
                                            </chainedmapper>
                                        </mapper>
                                    </pathconvert>
                                    <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/config.properties">
                                        <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${bundles} file:modules/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                                        <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                                    </propertyfile>
                                    <copy file="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}" tofile="${project.build.directory}/felix.jar"/>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptors>
                                    <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/assembly/felix.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>run-on-felix</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.main</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.3</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.gogo.shell:0.6.1 useless from Maven since stdin is swallowed -->
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <property name="vm.args" value=""/>
                            <pathconvert property="plugins.jars" pathsep="${path.separator}">
                                <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                <map from="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}classes" to=""/>
                            </pathconvert>
                            <makeurl property="urls" separator=" ">
                                <path path="${plugins.jars}"/>
                                <path location="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"/>
                            </makeurl>
                            <propertyfile file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties">
                                <entry key="felix.auto.start" value="${urls}"/>
                                <entry key="felix.auto.deploy.action" value="uninstall,install,update,start"/>
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.storage" value="${project.build.directory}${file.separator}felix-cache"/>
                                <entry key="org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" value="*"/>
                            </propertyfile>
                            <makeurl property="run.properties.url" file="${project.build.directory}/run.properties"/>
                            <java fork="true" jar="${maven.dependency.org.apache.felix.org.apache.felix.main.jar.path}">
                                <sysproperty key="felix.config.properties" value="${run.properties.url}"/>
                                <jvmarg line="${vm.args}"/>
                            </java>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Agradecería si alguien puede aclararme esta duda.

Comment: Revisa que tengas configurado de manera correcta el maven en Netbeans, este es el error. "The parameters 'url' for goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> "